# Zoom the listview

Tags: android, listview, zooming

I have a listview containing a textview and I need to zoom this textview on button click but I am not able to do it, I tried everything to override the simplecursor adapter and override the getview() method but couldn't zoom the textview on button click, the button is outside the listview and my code is:

this is the listview layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/bt_rating"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star"
 android:onClick="onclick"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/FontSizeInListView"
android:gravity="right"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
                Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view 
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){


            if(view.getId() == R.id.text1){
            tv=(TextView)view;          
            }}**
```

so that way I get the textview but sure only the last one created will be rendered and in the zoom I do `tv.settextsize(..)`
but only the last textview created on page will change because I only have the id of that one so how can I get all the textviews and not just the last one created?

Comment: You will need a custom list Adapter. If you're already using one, can you post your getView method?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom adapter, add a variable (with public setters and getters) to represent zoom level. In your `getView` method, use this variable to change the text views' text sizes (just add that right before your return line. You must always set the size to something, since the views are reused.

Then on your button that changes the zoom level, change the adapter's zoom variable and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it to force it to call `getView` on all its visible views. (This is assuming you subclassed ArrayAdapter).

Comment: I think It started to work, I did something else and it started to work.. will see that tomorrow.. because in my method I've got a textview that got bigger and few others but the rest stayed the same will see how to fix that.. but at least it worked..

Comment: If you aren't modifying it in `getView`, you're going to have a lot of unpredictable behavior like you just described. A list view regularly recycles views that just scrolled off the screen to use as new views that are scrolling onto the screen. When a view is recycled, it only changes what you tell it to change in `getView`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked What I did is:

```
adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title","Fav"}, new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.bt_rating},CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);   
          //added in last update
            adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
                   /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
                public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){


                    if(view.getId() == R.id.text1){
                    tv=(TextView)view;     
                    tv.setTextSize(SizeOfTextInListView);
                    }
```

});

And in the zoom button:

```
 //zoom in button click
        final Button zoom_in_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zoom_in);
        zoom_in_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(Zoom_counter<10){
                  SizeOfTextInListView= SizeOfTextInListView+Zoom_In_Out_value;
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Zoom_counter++;


            }
            } 
        });
```

and it worked perfectly..